# Hide the short lines of axis tickers in plt.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to hide the tickers (but not the ticker labels) for my plots (plt.subplots). It is doable if the axes are not shared by those subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 0.0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 0.0

dat = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for i in range(4):
  dat[i].plot(ax=axs[i // 2, i % 2])
```

[image]

However, if axes are shared, the tickers appear. They look quite ugly and I wonder if there is a way to disable them.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i in range(4):
  dat[i].plot(ax=axs[i // 2, i % 2])
```

[image]

Comment: Something like: `[ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) for ax in axs[0]]` and 
`[ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False) for ax in axs[:, 1]]` make the trick

Comment: As per the duplicate I linked `for ax in axs.ravel(): ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)` will do what you want.

Comment: @Lucas I don't think your dupe is appropriate, and the code in your second comment is bad form (creating a listcomp for a side effect).

Comment: You are right, @AndrasDeak, in both things :)